# Local Web Application Not Loading, Failed Bokeh Plot Inline Embedding

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, bokeh

I'm building a Python web application that makes use of the Bokeh library. I would like to use Bokeh's inline embedding process to display plots in the html page, however something's going wrong and I am having difficulty with finding the error(s) I've made.

When I run my app locally and try generating a Bokeh plot, the following error comes up: "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand"

I have fairly little experience with Python & programming in general, so I apologise if my code is clumsy at times.

I am not running a Bokeh server, and from what I understood in the documentation, it isn't necessary for this form of embedding (?). If there's an alternative way of embedding plots in the html w/o using a Bokeh server, please do share.

In the html, I've added the Bokeh script and link tags:

```
<head>   
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href=
"http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel="stylesheet">
<link
    href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.1.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
{{ script }}
</head>
```

I've also added the {{ div }} value to the html body.

The relevant controller.py code looks as follows:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = Regression(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        if request.form['btn'] == 'Plot Regression':
            regr = reg(form.ticker.data, form.months.data)
            b1, b2, b3, r, a = regr.b1, regr.b2, regr.b3, regr.r2, regr.a
            script, div = plotreg(b3, a, regr.xreturn, regr.yreturn)
        else:
            script, div = plotprice(form.ticker.data, form.months.data)
            b1, b2, b3, r, a = None, None, None, None, None
    else:
        b1, b2, b3, r, a, script, div = None, None, None, None, None, None, None
    return render_template('index.html',form=form, b1=b1, b2=b2, b3=b3, r=r, a=a, script=script, div=div)
```

If there's an error in my code, it should be somewhere here... Otherwise perhaps I'm missing something?  Any help would be much appreciated!